# What is the easiest way to do 'is' in Java?

Tags: java, typechecking

Many languages have a facility to check to see if an Object is of a certain type (including parent subclasses), implemented with 'is' and used like this:

```
if(obj is MyType)
```

Or slightly more tediously you can in other languages check by using the 'as' keyword to do a soft typecast and seeing if the result null.

I haven't used Java in years and I'm getting back up to speed on it but surely Java has a way to easily do this without delving deep into the Reflection APIs?

Thanks in advance for answers.  I have searched both here and other places but the keywords involved are so generic that even though I'm sure this has a simple answer, googling for it is hard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if (objectReference instanceof type){
    //Your code goes here
}
```

More info [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm).

Answer (score 7):

You can only use `instanceof` with a class literal: that is:

```
Class type = String.class;

if (myObj instanceof String) // will compile

if (myObj instanceof type) //will not compile
```

The alternative is to use the method `Class.isInstance`

```
if (type.isInstance(myObj)) // will compile
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj instanceof TargetType` returns true just in case `TargetType` is in the type hierarchy that contains `obj`.

See [Sun's tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)